# How can I set a value in the context in a Django view decorator?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I want to write a decorator that will provide values to the template rendering context, like so:

```
@deco(art=Nouveau)
def my_wall(request):
    # should have art == 'something' in the template
    return render_from_template('plain_white.html', {art:'something'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@deco(art=Nouveau)
def my_wall(request):
    # should have art == Nouveau in the template
    return render_from_template('plain_white.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My initial attempt at implementing it looked something like this:

```
class deco(object):

    def __init__(self, art=None):
        self.art = art

    def __call__(self, f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.art:
                request.setdefault('art', self.art)

            return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This, however, does not work because the request isn't a real dict.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this would be if the decorator itself is responsible for rendering and returning the template. And there is quite a well-established snippet that does exactly this: the [render_to](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/821/) decorator. The idea is that your view just returns a dictionary, and the decorator actually renders it. You should be able to edit that snippet so that it handles the defaults situation.